# Strongswan ipsec site to site vpn to aws virtual private gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I have configured ipsec tunnel between strongswan and aws vpc. Below is my ipsec conf:

```
----
   config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=no

conn vpc
       mobike=no
       type=tunnel
       compress=no
       keyexchange=ikev1
       ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
       ikelifetime=28800s
       esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024
       lifetime=3600s
       rekeymargin=3m
       keyingtries=3
       dpddelay=10s
       dpdtimeout=30s
       dpdaction=restart
       authby=psk
       leftid=x.x.x.x
       leftsubnet=x.x.x.x

conn tunnel1
       also=vpc
       auto=start
       right=x.x.x.x
       rightsubnet=x.x.x.x
conn tunnel2
       also=vpc
       auto=start
       right=x.x.x.x
       rightsubnet=x.x.x.x
```

Tunnel establishes and works fine but after every 3 to 4 hours connection gets lost but the tunnel status shows up. I everytime have to restart ipsec two three times at once to get it on working condition. 
There is no problem with single tunnel, it works fine. As soon as i bring up the second tunnel the connection gets disturbed.

Please help.

Comment: Run the `tcpdump` on both ends when issue happens.

Comment: I cannot do anything like viewing log on aws side